# spring boot callbackUrl ConnectSupport

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social

I want to overload callbackUrl in ConnectSupport

I use Spring boot Connect : org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile

```
@Bean
public ConnectController connectController(
        ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
        ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {

    ConnectController controller = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator,
            connectionRepository);

        controller.set callbackUrl  ??
        return controller;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Social Api is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/).  You need to call the setApplicationUrl().

```
@Bean
public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
        ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {

    ConnectController controller = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator,
            connectionRepository);
        String url = "www.foo.com";
        controller.setApplicationUrl(url) ;
        return controller;

}
```

Comment: But NullPointerException !! In ConnectSupport

public void setApplicationUrl(String applicationUrl) {
        connectSupport.setApplicationUrl(applicationUrl);
    }
connectSupport is null

Comment: You saved my life http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724835/spring-boot-social-connector-behind-reverse-proxy

Comment: @jee I see no way to have connectSupport null in spring-social code see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/master/spring-social-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ConnectController.java#L411

Answer (score 0):

At this point (NullPointerException problem) one way to solve the problem is to extend ConnectController (and ProviderSignInController which suffers the same issue) and fix the offending portion of the code yourself. Just adding the classes into project works. Is it elegant? Well...

```
/*******************************************************************/
//RedirectedConnectController.java

public class RedirectedConnectController extends ConnectController {

    @Value("${application.url}")
    private String appUrl;

    public RedirectedConnectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, 
                                       ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    /*
     * This is the method, which should be called BEFORE setApplicationUrl
     * but obviously is not. 
     */    
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        setApplicationUrl(appUrl);
    }
}
/*******************************************************************/
//RedirectedSignInController.java

@Controller
public class RedirectedSignInController extends ProviderSignInController {

    @Value("${application.url}")
    private String appUrl;

    @Inject
    public RedirectedSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, 
                                      UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, 
                                      SignInAdapter signInAdapter) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, signInAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        setApplicationUrl(appUrl);
    }
}
```