# Spring-boot social connector behind (reverse) proxy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social

I've deployed my spring-boot app behind a proxy (currently apache but will be the same using nginx or varnish, ...) so I receive the

```
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/signin/google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

more or less the same for other social such as Facebook.

The docs state you should configure like this

```
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController() {
        ConnectController controller = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator(), connectionRepository());
        controller.setApplicationUrl(environment.getProperty("application.url");
        return controller;
    }
}
```

see http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#creating-connections-with-connectcontroller

How I'm I supposed to get `connectionFactoryLocation()` from ?

My code is:

```
/**
 * Basic Spring Social configuration.
 *
 * <p>Creates the beans necessary to manage Connections to social services and
 * link accounts from those services to internal Users.</p>
 */
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfiguration implements SocialConfigurer {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    private SocialUserConnectionRepository socialUserConnectionRepository;      

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {

        // Google configuration
        String googleClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.google.clientId");
        String googleClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.google.clientSecret");
        if (googleClientId != null && googleClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring GoogleConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new GoogleConnectionFactory(
                    googleClientId,
                    googleClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure GoogleConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // Facebook configuration
        String facebookClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.clientId");
        String facebookClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.clientSecret");
        if (facebookClientId != null && facebookClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring FacebookConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                    facebookClientId,
                    facebookClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure FacebookConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // Twitter configuration
        String twitterClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.twitter.clientId");
        String twitterClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.twitter.clientSecret");
        if (twitterClientId != null && twitterClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring TwitterConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new TwitterConnectionFactory(
                    twitterClientId,
                    twitterClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure TwitterConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // jhipster-needle-add-social-connection-factory
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new CustomSocialUsersConnectionRepository(socialUserConnectionRepository, connectionFactoryLocator);
    }

    @Bean
    public SignInAdapter signInAdapter() {
        return new CustomSignInAdapter();
    }

    @Inject
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, SignInAdapter signInAdapter) throws Exception {
        ProviderSignInController providerSignInController = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, signInAdapter);
        providerSignInController.setSignUpUrl("/social/signup");
        providerSignInController.setApplicationUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.application.url"));

        return providerSignInController;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInUtils getProviderSignInUtils(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        return new ProviderSignInUtils(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27593526/509565 I've rewritten `connectController()` as

```
@Bean
public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
        ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {

    ConnectController controller = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    controller.setApplicationUrl(environment.getProperty("application.url"));
    return controller;
}
```